# How do I download a binary file (in this case, an image) from a webserver using C sockets?

Tags: c, image, sockets, http, download

Okay, so basically I need to download a .jpg or .png image from a webserver using C sockets.

I'm making a little homebrew application for the Wii with which you can browse Reddit. The program already gets the posts from the front page using an HTTP request, but I can't figure out how I can download an image. I have tried multiple things in the past few days and I am clueless.

Here's what I have implemented so far:

(net_read or net_write are equivalent to read or write on linux, this is so it works on the wii)

```c
struct post {
    char author[25];
    char subreddit[25];
    char title[300];
    char url[300];
    int score;
}; //Included this for context

struct post i = fp_data[index]; //Getting data from received posts

char* url = malloc(300*sizeof(char));
strcpy(url, i.url);
url+=8; //Remove 'http://'
char* tempurl = malloc(300*sizeof(char)); //tempurl so strtok doesn't screw with the url
strcpy(tempurl, url);

int portno = 80;
char delimiter[] = "/";
char *host = strtok(tempurl, delimiter);
char *requestend = url;
requestend+=strlen(host);
// example values:
// host = i.imgur.com
// requestend = /ROQnhvC.jpg

    if(strstr(url,".png") != NULL){
        struct hostent *server;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        int sockfd, bytes, sent, total, message_size;
        char *message;
        char response[1024] = {0};

        message_size=0;
            message_size+=strlen("GET  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: \r\n")+strlen(requestend)+strlen(host);
            message_size+=strlen("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");

        message=malloc(message_size);
            sprintf(message,"GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n",requestend, host);
            strcat(message,"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");

        printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

        sockfd = net_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) printf("ERROR opening socket");

        //int yes = 1;
        //net_setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &yes, sizeof(int));

        server = net_gethostbyname(host);
        if (server == NULL) printf("ERROR, no such host");

        memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

        if (net_connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            printf("ERROR connecting");

        total = strlen(message);
        sent = 0;
        do {
            bytes = net_write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
            if (bytes < 0)
                printf("ERROR writing message to socket");
            if (bytes == 0)
                break;
            sent+=bytes;
        } while (sent < total);

        FILE* fp;
        char pth[20];
        sprintf(pth, "sd://tex%d.png", index); 
        fp = fopen(pth, "wb"); //Writing to a file so I can see the results
        int n = 0;

        n = net_read(sockfd, response, 1024);

        if(n < 1){
            printf("read() failed");
            return;
        }
        char* ss = strstr(response, "\r\n\r\n")+4; //Cut '\r\n\r\n' so the http response is gone
        fwrite(ss, sizeof(char), strlen(ss), fp);

        while((n = net_recv(sockfd, response, 1024, 0)) >= 1){
            fwrite(response,sizeof(response),1,fp);
            memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
            if(n < 1024){
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
        net_close(sockfd);
    }
```

This should return a valid .jpg file, but it doesn't really work. If I put the raw data next to the source file's raw data, there are big differences. Also I can't view it. What's the issue here?

Comment: I recommend using [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: @nivpeled I am unable to since I am working on a Wii Homebrew Application

Comment: what is your compiler? what is the HW you compiler for?

Comment: start with seeing what data is transmitted over the network, you can use tcpdump/wireshark..

Comment: @nivpeled GCC using devkitpro

Comment: @DeltaTwoForce Then I do not understand what stops you from using libcurl

Comment: @nivpeled libcurl doesn't exist for the wii

Comment: regarding error messages like: `printf("ERROR connecting");`   This is meaningless to the user.  When outputting an error message, output it to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When outputting an error message from a call to a C library function, call `perror()` as that outputs both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: `libcurl` talks to the socket, it doesn't care what the transport mechanism is implemented by

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other reasons, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: You are ignoring 'n' in the data fwrite() call and using sizeof() instead.  That will not work reliably, especially with the partial read at the end of the file.  You must correctly and completely handle the result returned by system calls like recv().

Comment: @user3629249 The code does not compile since it is a snippet of the code which contains the important things. I apologize if I had to post the entire code.

Comment: ...and, with general binary data, the memset is just a waste of cycles.

Comment: on stackoverflow, when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, to be 'on topic, need to follow the items found at: [mcve]

Comment: Off by 1 with `strcat(message,"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");`.  Use `message=malloc(message_size + 1);`

Comment: @DeltaTwoForce libcurl is open source, take the sources and build it using your toolchain.